# Add controls to TabPage, only first label is getting added

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

Trying to add controls to a tabPage, only first label is getting added, not sure of the problem, please check

```
int X = 230;
int Y = 10;

ArrayList Lbls = new ArrayList();
Lbls.Add("Lbls_1");
Lbls.Add("Lbls_2");
Lbls.Add("Lbls_3");
Lbls.Add("Lbls_4");
Lbls.Add("Lbls_5");

foreach (object obj in Lbls)
{
    Label LblsAdd = new Label();
    LblsAdd.AutoSize = true;
    LblsAdd.Text = obj.ToString();
    LblsAdd.Left = X + 50;
    LblsAdd.Top = Y;
    LblsAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 15); 
    MyTabPage.Controls.Add(LblsAdd);
}
```

Comment: the labels are at the same location. you should change X in for loop

Comment: Am adding "+50" to the left, is it wrong?

Comment: it's wrong. above this line, add `X+=35;`

Comment: OMG! Yeah..such a silly mistake. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, all Labels are on the same location because at each iteration `X` remains to be 230 + 50 = 280.
You need to increment this variable so that for the next label you can use the updated result:

```
foreach (object obj in Lbls)
{
    Label LblsAdd = new Label();
    LblsAdd.AutoSize = true;
    LblsAdd.Text = obj.ToString();
    X = X + 50;  // write a new value into the variable X
    LblsAdd.Left = X;
    LblsAdd.Top = Y;
    LblsAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 15); 
    MyTabPage.Controls.Add(LblsAdd);
}
```